# Shannon entropy with regards to independent random variables

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

I had a question regarding a question on Shannon entropy I came across. It has to do with representing entropy in the form of their probability distributions, but let me elaborate. Here's the specific problem I'm referring to:

$\space$

Consider three independent random variables $u$, $v$, and $w$ with entropies $H_u$, $H_v$, $H_w$. Let,

$$X \equiv (U,\ V)$$
$$Y \equiv (V,\ W)$$

What is $H(X, Y)$, $H(X | Y)$, and $I(X; Y)$?

$\space$

Here's what I've come up with so far:

Since the random variables $u$, $v$, and $w$ are independent,

$$P(X) = P(U)P(V)$$
$$P(Y) = P(V)P(W)$$

And since
$$P(X, Y) = P(X|Y)P(Y)$$
$$P(X|Y) = \frac{P(Y|X)P(U)}{P(W)}$$

But I'm not sure how to progress further from here... The solution my instructor provided for this particular problem in the textbook I'm using (*Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms*) is that:

$$P(X|Y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{c}
P(U)\ (x_2 = y_1) \\
0\ (else)
\end{array}
\right.$$

$$P(X, Y) = \left\{\begin{array}{c} P(U)P(V)P(W)\ (x_2 = y_1) \\ 0\ (else) \end{array}\right.$$

And with this result the solution is fairly easy to derive.

$\space$

What I'm wondering is, where did the $x_2 = y_1$ come from, and how were the results for those probability distributions come to be? The approach I was taking was causing me to go in circles without any real results.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it help to clarify if you try to express   $P(X=(x_1, x_2), Y=(y_1, y_2))$  in terms of  $P(U=something), P(V=something), P(W=something)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the typical scenario that I would imagine. However, the textbook I'm using doesn't say anything about that, nor does it mention anything about there being two outcomes. I don't know where my instructor got the idea from either...

Comment: What do you mean by two outcomes? It says $X=(U,V)$, so $X$ clearly consists of two "components", whatever they are  (e.g., if $U=foo$ and $V=5$, then $X=(foo, 5)$, in other words, $x_1=foo$ and $x_2=5$).

Answer (score 0):

Since $X = (U, V)$ and $Y = (V, W)$ share the variable $V$ in any observation of both $X =x$ and $Y=y$ there is only one fixed value for $V=v$ so that that $x_2 = v = y_1$.

Thus, any outcome where $x_2 \neq y_1$ is impossible and gets zero probability.